# Console log response data returned data but not state

Tags: reactjs

When I did a `console.log(response.data)` in the `loadingData()`, it returned the result as 2 arrays:

```
{user: {…}, postedby: Array(2)}
```

here is the code for the console log:

```
 const[userProfile,setUserProfile] = useState([])

   useEffect(()=>{
        loadingData()
       
    },[])

    const loadingData = async() => {
        const response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/user/${userid}`, {withCredentials:true})
        setUserProfile(response.data)      
        console.log(response.data) 
    }
```

But when I did a `console.log(userProfile)` in the `useEffect`, it returned an empty array:

[ ]

```
const[userProfile,setUserProfile] = useState([])
    
       useEffect(()=>{
            loadingData()
            console.log(userProfile) 
           
        },[])

            const loadingData = async() => {
            const response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/user/${userid}`, {withCredentials:true})
            setUserProfile(response.data) 
          
        }
```

I am lost and wondering what I have missed. Any help greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance. Thanks

Comment: What happen if you console.log `userProfile` outside the useEffect?

Comment: it returned this: [ ] 
 [ ]
 {user: {…}, postedby: Array(2)}

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `useEffect` with an empty dependency array will only be called when the component is mounted. So at that time, the `userProfile` is an empty array. This is because `loadingData()` is an async function.

So the execution flow will be like:

1. Call `loadingData()`.
2. Console log `userProfile` where it is empty.
3. Execute `loadingData()`.
4. Update `userProfile`

So what you can do now, is use 2 `useEffect`s.
One to call `loadingData()` with an empty dependency array and other to log it with `userProfile` in the dependency array.

Like this

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(userProfile) 
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(userProfile) 
},[userProfile])
```

Now every time the `userProfile` is updated the `useEffect` with `userProfile` in the dependency array will be called, thus logging it.

Refer [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) about `useEffect` and dependency array

Comment: you'll get into an infinite loop, cause you execute loadingData function every time userProfile changes, but in loadingData you change the userProfile value, so you'll never stop to execute the function

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 `useEffect` : 1 that triggers the function, and 1 that catches the changes of the `userProfile` state value,

If you only use one `useEffect` to do these 2 actions, you'll get into an infinite loop because you'll execute the function every time `userProfile` changes but your function changes this value...

```
   const[userProfile,setUserProfile] = useState([])

   useEffect(()=>{
        const loadingData = async() => {
            const response = await Axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/user/user/${userid}`, {withCredentials:true})
            setUserProfile(response.data) 
        }
       loadingData();
    },[])

   useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(userProfile)
    },[userProfile])
```

Comment: thanks. but it always returned an empty array first followed by dataset. here is the results:[ ]
{user: {…}, postedby: Array(2)}

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that setting state in react is asynchronous so you won't see it reflected immediately. Under the hood react batches calls to set state so it doesn't render the component every time state changes